# How to add the javascript in display tag sort event?

Tags: displaytag

Hi i am using display tag to display the data. on clicking on the table header link it should call the javascript and submits the page instead of navigation to it. how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Onload of the page, seach for the sort column and add the script to submit the page as follows,

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('.sortable').each(function(event){ 
                     var obj = $(this).find('a').attr('href'); 
                var urltext = 'javascript:submitform("'+contextPath+'/'+obj+'\")';  
                $(this).find('a').attr('href', urltext);
            }); 
      });
```